# STM32F4 HSE clock frequency without HSE

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

I am using an STM32F446ZE Nucleo Board which does NOT have an external HSE clock. From CubeMX I set the clock input from the HSE and after in the clock configuration I set the system clock to 180MHz.
[image]

and in the clock configuration I set the PLL like this
[image]

The code generated by CubeMX seems to be correct also.[image]
My point is that even if I don't have an HSE in the board the uController works in 180MHz. How is this possible? What is the clock input after all?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running at 180 MHz?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure because I had set the TIM1 when it was clocked at 16MHz to toggle an LED every 1 second and now that it's clock peripheral is at 90MHz (theoretically) it blinks almost 6 times faster (9*16 = 96MHz) so yes I can say that it runs in this frequency.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual code which CubeMX generated to see how the clocks are configured? It may just be ignoring your HSE setting and using HSI instead.

Comment: No it uses the HSE check the edit.

Comment: Take a look at the schematic for your Nucleo F446 board. you'll see that U2, the ST-LINK JTAG interface IC appears to have its PA8 pin connected to the STM32F466's OSC-IN pin with a net labelled "MCO". Looks to me as though the ST-LINK is providing that HSE clock.

Comment: Yeah you are right I see. But still it should have worked with bypass option not with ceramic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Nucleo board you can drive the HSE from the STLINK clock (just choose the bypass option in your cubemx.

It is possible in some circumstances that the HSE can be driven by the bypass clock even if the pin is not configured properly.

To check it step through the clock startup routine (using the debugger) and see if the HSE clock has started properly. Then you will not have to guess.